# Default path used by a java class in blazeds

Tags: java, blazeds

I'm using Blazeds with java and flex, I need one of the java classes to read from a .dat file, and since the application is to be hosted on the server i am not providing a path to the file, ie I'm using:

```
input = new FileReader("file.dat");
```

In a standard java application I'd put the file in the project folder, however since the class is being used through blaze ds, does any one have any idea where I should place this file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably should put it into your `WEB-INF/` directory.

```
URL url = FlexContext.getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/file.dat")
input = new FileReader(url.getFile());
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a related problem, however I tried another method that i have which interacts with a mysql database. this worked fine in local host, but now that i have uploaded it to a server a it cant seem to find the driver (which is still in the same folder o the server that it was on local host). The exect error returned is: faultCode:Server.Processing faultString:'java.sql.SQLException : No suitable driver. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: It's probably not related unless you want file.dat to be on the classpath.